# Set DatabaseInitializerForType in config file for Custom Initializer to fire

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, initialization, entity-framework-6, app-config

So I either get errors firing or nothing happens.  I know that I have custom Entity Framework Initializer like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EasyEntity
{
    public class EasyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EasyContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(EasyContext context)
        {
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person { FirstName = "Waz", LastName = "Amattau"},
                new Person { FirstName = "Helena", LastName = "Handbasket"},
            };

            foreach (var person in persons)
                context.Person.Add(person);

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

I can call this when I set this quite easily:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EasyEntity
{
    public class EasyContext : DbContext
    {
        public EasyContext() : base("name=EasyEntity")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<EasyContext>(new EasyInitializer());   
        }

        public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Yet this is all in a class library and when I have a console app to test this it will not fire in the app.config.  I am ultimately looking to create builds or what not or apps to fire or not fire based on environment.  After scouring the internet it seems many different people label and put different text in this config setting.  I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 according to NuGet, yet the config and references claim 6.0.0 and have wondered if this has changed and how to make it fire from a seperate project without having to hardcdoe the intializer to fire.  I have this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DatabaseInitializerForType EasyEntity.EasyInitializer, EasyEntity" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have tried setting 'value' to lots of things like 'Enabled', 'EasyEntity.EasyInitializer, EasyEntity', 'true', 'comeonpleasefire'.  But nothing appears to work as I am ignorant of what to do.  I saw another blog putting the setting inside the entityFramework node in the config section but that did not work either.  My total config setting in my console app for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DatabaseInitializerForType EasyEntity.EasyInitializer, EasyEntity" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EasyEntity" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=.;Database=Easy;Integrated Security=True;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What's the error? Also, why call SeedIt from the constructor since it is called from the overriden Seed method?

Comment: I updated my answer.  There is no error, there is nothing is the problem.  I would expect to be able to call the initializer and seeding to take place.  I was using the constructor in desperation and setting a breakpoint to see if it was getting hit.  I removed it and just did the override Seed to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't pick up values from the `appSettings` section of your application configuration file. Instead you need to use [`entityFramework.contexts.context.databaseInitializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx) section, something like this should do it:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <contexts>
        <context type="EasyEntity.EasyContext, EasyEntity">
            <databaseInitializer type="EasyEntity.EasyInitializer, EasyEntity" />
        </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you.   I am curious if I could run this at a build time event and then after that the initializer would not go off everytime I hit the context.  I could potentially just ensure my environment is wiped and then set the setting 'createifnotexists' instead of 'dropcreatealways'.  I ultimately want to have this work with a build process for database population and seeding for test environments from builds if possible in a self contained library replacing an old school Database Project.

Comment: I'd probably just create another initialiser, one that inherits from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` instead for example. Then use the app config transformations to decide which one is used. (i.e. Release gets DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges)

Answer (score 0):

EF does not run the initializer until you use the the context or explicitly tell EF to create the db.

Try this in you console application

```
using (var context = new EasyContext ())
{
    // Uncomment this line to see the raw sql commands
    //context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
    context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    context.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Comment: From what I am reading from tutorials that is not the case claimed by others.  The idea is that I may be deploying to a test database where I want to in a config seed the data always or in production not.  I may have Dev, QA, UAT, Prod settings.  I may want to configure a build or such that fires to replace the data or not based on config values.  I could create multiple classes for the contexts with slight variations but that seems silly to me if a config could access this and supposedly from what I am reading it should work. I just have not seen a good example yet of it working.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer the original question you **can** set the Initializer in the **appSettings**.
You can use reflection to set the Initializer like so:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="DatabaseInitializerForType EasyEntity.EasyContext, EasyEntity" value="System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1[[EasyEntity.EasyContext, EasyEntity]], EntityFramework" />
```

You may have been confused by 'disabled' with the answer far different than setting it to 'enabled' or 'true'.  If you want to run a 'seed' method you could use access the initializer class with the following.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="DatabaseInitializerForType EasyEntity.EasyContext, EasyEntity"  value="EasyEntity.EasyInitializer, EasyEntity" />
```